# Child process gets low integrity after acrobat reader was executed

Tags: windows, vb.net

On our RDS hosts, we run a custom made (vb.net) menu system that allows our users to shell other apps we wrote. So basically it's a vb.net app that shells other vb.net apps. This worked for many years, but since a few months, we noticed that something strange... after a user opens acrobat reader, all the apps that are shelled from our menu app get low integrity level, causing them to fail. All the user can do to fix this, is log off and then log on again.

Oh, we even have some VB6 apps in our menu (I know...) and they have the exact same issue.

[Process Explorer screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J8Yyb.png)

I've tried reading up on all this integrity mechanism stuff, but I don't see any reason for this behavior. Here's the code that shells an app:

```
Dim PSI As New ProcessStartInfo
With PSI
    .Arguments = Arguments
    .WorkingDirectory = WorkingDirectory
    .FileName = Executable
    .UseShellExecute = True
End With

Dim P As Process = Process.Start(PSI)


'Executable:       "C:\Program Files\<path>\<appname>.EXE"
'Arguments:        "/NET=BHDMGR /USERLEVEL=3 /SYSLOG=False"
'WorkingDirectory: "C:\Program Files\<path>\
```

Any hints about how to debug this, are very welcome!

Comment: Probably not the answer that you're going to like, but simple fix is don't use acrobat reader on in RDS environment if you can avoid it.  Seen it many times over last couple years, updates to either windows or acrobat reader, it's just got progressively worse.  It might have some cool features, but I've found most people just want to view a pdf doc and don't need all the bells and whistles.

Comment: Any (free) pdf reader you can recommend instead? I don't want them to use Chrome for that... we mostly use published apps, and some of them can open a pdf.. if it opens Chrome instead of Acrobat Reader, then users might go surfing the web on the rds hosts, and we don't need that

Comment: There are many, maybe check on https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ Foxit is one I see around frequently, but I normally use just use browsers